# Posicionar elemento con CSS (z-index no funciona)

Tags: css

excelente día a todos, espero me puedan ayudar
quiero posicionar la nube debajo del elemento que se ve más oscuro, pero lamentablemente no he podido lograrlo, cabe resaltar que use z-index tanto en la nube como en el contenedor pero lamentablemente no sucedió nada, alguien me puede ayudar a solucionar este problema, lo agradecería muchisimo

Mi contenedor es asi

```
<div class="banner-section">
<img src="src/img/nubes-efecto-paralax.svg" alt="" class="nube-img">
```

y las propiedades CSS de la imagen son estas:

```
.nube-img{
width: 100%;
position: absolute;
margin-top: 170px;
}
```

[image: Nube debe estar abajo del contenedor mas verde]

Comment: Deberías agregar el código completo sobre como tienes montado tu HTML y tu CSS que afecta a dicha nube ya que si no no podemos reproducirlo.

Comment: Explica como has utilizado el z-index porque a priori debería funcionar.

Comment: Postea el codigo completo, ya que asi es dificil reproducir el problema. O al menos comparte la forma en que usas z-index

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Para que funcione Z-index correctamente debes cumplir con unas condiciones**, principalmente se usa de la siguiente forma:

```
<main class="padre">
  <div class="hermano uno">
    <img class="hijo" src=".png"/>
  </div>
  <div class="hermano dos">
  </div>
</main>
```

Principalmente para que funcionen las capas de z-index, deben estar al mismo nivel de parentesco, por ejemplo con el código anterior el z-index funcionará con los dos **"hermanos"**, pero no funcionará entre el **hijo** y el **hermano dos**. Lo otro que es necesario agregar es **position: relative**, **fixed** o **absolute** según sea el caso. Entonces las condiciones, formalmente escritas serían:

- Los elementos situados en capas, **deben estar al mismo nivel de jerarquía** en la maquetación html.
- Deben tener declarado **position** diferente al default que es **static**.
- Los elementos anidados en una capa inferior o superior, heredarán la capa declarada en su contenedor, pero **nunca se superpondran al nivel declarado al ancestro contenedor ni a los elementos "hermanos" al padre**.

El error más tipico es creer que esto funcionará en css, así:

```
.hermano, .hijo {position: relative;}

.hijo{z-index: 1; }

.hermano.dos {z-index: 9999}
```

Sí la imagen "hijo", es mayor que la altura del "hermano uno" esta se sobrepondra al "hermano dos", por lo que al querer corregir esto se intenta usar un z-index en el "hermano dos" altísimo para tratar sin resultados de corregir esto, pero como te mencione, al no estar al mismo nivel, el hijo y el hermano dos, esto nunca funcionará, en este caso, **hay que declarar el z-index en los dos hermanos y aumentar el valor en el que va a sobreponerse**, así:

```
.hermano, .hijo {position: relative;}

.hermano.uno {z-index: 1}

.hijo{}

.hermano.dos {z-index: 2}
```

Espero que haya quedado claro, o que efectivamente sea el error que se te presenta, lo cierto es que como muchos han comentado tú código puesto en la pregunta, no reproduce el error y es muy difícil saber como ayudarte de mejor manera. Éxitos!